# Redirection errors

Tags: redirect

I was trying to change how my website is routed by changing the URL from somebody's old host to mine.  From bjj.iamrobbiegreen.com to gladiatorbjj.net under settings and site URL.  I now cannot get into the settings to make any changes.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this without having to rebuild the site?  All I have is the xml source code and the guy who originally created the site is MIA.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get in over FTP then [edit `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php)

```
define('WP_HOME','http://bjj.iamrobbiegreen.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://bjj.iamrobbiegreen.com');
```

Or you can [change it directly in the database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database). Prefer the first method.

You may have server level configuration issues though. Its hard to tell. Resetting back to the original URL should at least get you back into the site. Then you can [work on migrating the site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change).

Comment: Ok awesome thanks for the information.  so regardless I need to get FTP access to the  original file. So I need the original creator for  this. Thanks for the help..:)

Comment: Yes, you need some kind of access-- ftp, database, cPanel, something-- to do this.