# Accidentally changed the url

Tags: urls

I happened to accidentally change the url from my website ...
I have read a so many articles about what to do and I understand that I probably need to change something from a database, and that it is easiest to do through phpmyadmin, but when I get there it looks nothing like the guides i've been watching. I can't find anywhere I can log in, but it seems that I should download it ... so then I did it and it felt like it seemed more like a strange search tool ...

I do not understand, someone please help me!!

Comment: Codex has multiple methods on [Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), please elaborate on what have you tried and which steps are not clear for you.

Comment: okay what i've done step by step?

Comment: Which article you are trying to follow, etc. And please do look through Codex docs I linked above, some methods might be easier for you than others.

Comment: okay what i've done step by step?
first i changed the both url at the settings, but the site got all very messy, so i tried to change it back and save again, which did'nt work. I watched this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=THzF3Xh9H8M#! and i understood it all until 2.23 when he starts to talk about a controlpanel and phpmyadmin, i got lost cause it seesms like i can't find the right website. and i certainly can't fing anywhere to log in.

Comment: This would be my recommendation: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82400/21376 It is really straight out of the Codex (see @Rarst's link).

Comment: I still don't get it, i know my brain is a mess, but what is the really first step, to change the codex in ftp (?) i need to use for example cpanel, right? but how do i use it...?
I am so greatful for the help, i really am!!!

Answer (score 2):

Re: the comments above: Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

It says:

> There are four easy methods to change the Site URL manually. Any of
>   these methods will work and perform much the same function.

And the Codex outlines each one. The first one is the easiest; add these lines to wp-config.php with FTP or your hosting control panel file manager:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```